# Need help converting date format

Tags: r, date

I have a csv file where the dates look like this: `Jan 31, 2017`

I would like it be `2017-01-31`

I've been searching the site and I found a lot of similar questions but none with my strange date format.

EDIT: Was unclear. I need to change a lot of dates so doing it manually won't work. Thanks for suggestions, reading the help function of lubridate and strptime now.

Comment: `?strptime` will tell you all you need to know

Answer (score 3):

Use the `lubridate` library:

```
library(lubridate)
date <- "Jan 31, 2017"
date2 <- mdy(date)

date2
[1] "2017-01-31"
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer. I was a bit unclear though, I need to change all the dates in my file, doing it manually like this will be too time consuming.

Comment: @AlbertAlshamn then do it for the column: `df1$newDate <- mdy(df1$oldDate)`